# Matching an alphabet

Tags: regex, r, prefix

I'm trying to use the grep function in R to see which elements in the vector I have contain a letter of the alphabet. I can do it by creating a vector of elements that contain a single letter, but it would be ridiculous to do this for all 27 letters. Below is something I've tried:

```
 count <- grep(pattern = "a", names(file))
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Or `grep("[a-z]", names(file))`

Comment: 27 letters? are you matching `ñ`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
alpha.in.file <- names(file)[grep(pattern='[[:alpha:]]', names(file))]
```

This will allow you to extract the names of the file which contain only letters. To count them, simply

```
length(alpha.in.file)
```